# Optimize SQL statement with multiple CONCAT clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
*

FROM
pages


INNER JOIN cms_collection ON cms_collection.collection_id LIKE 

( 
   CONCAT('%', pages.page_id, '/heading%') OR
   CONCAT('%', pages.page_id, '/content%') 
)

WHERE
site_id = 51

LIMIT 10
```

The stacked CONCATs are causing the query to be super slow, is there anyway to optimize this? And actually it seems like this statement isn't working as expected.. I want to do a LIKE based on if the collection_id is '%pages.page_id/heading%' OR '%pages.page_id/content%'.

This statement works fine if just the first CONCAT exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OR` is a logical operator. It does not define alternatives for `LIKE`. You need to split that out into two `LIKE` clauses.

```
SELECT * FROM pages
INNER JOIN cms_collection ON
(cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT('%', pages.page_id, '/heading%')) OR
(cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT('%', pages.page_id, '/content%'))
WHERE site_id = 51 LIMIT 10
```

If that is still slow, add your table structure and the output of an `EXPLAIN` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pages
INNER JOIN cms_collection ON
(cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT('%', pages.page_id, '/heading%'))
WHERE site_id = 51

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM pages
INNER JOIN cms_collection ON
(cms_collection.collection_id LIKE CONCAT('%', pages.page_id, '/content%'))
WHERE site_id = 51 
LIMIT 10
;
```

Using UNION ALL instead of OR improves performance

Comment: I can't imagine that's faster than doing an OR in the WHERE clause.